# Update Iphone Application to Swift Coding

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've an application that I've developed before on xcode, now I want to make a new update for the application, but this time I'm going to build it from scratch using swift.

Now my question on iTunes connect will it accept the new update of the application that I built using swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why your update should not be accepted. If the only differences, is "it's written in Swift instead of ObjectiveC", this is obviously not the good reason the tell to Apple (and to the end user) for an update, but by rewriting from scratch, you probably will correct some bugs, and add a couple of new features that will be big enough to justify the update.

Comment: thank you, I didn't to start on swift and when uploading to iTunes get rejected

Comment: Just to help you, I've just rewritten one of my app from ObjectiveC to Swift, and being resubmitted without any problem